# Mongo error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am facing this error continuously.

```
 DBClientBase::findN: transport error()
```

I searched the problem and found that there are so many people who faced this problem but didn't find exact reason of this error. 
why this error is coming ?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to a network error connecting to the mongod server or a mongos cannot connect to the mongod.

The first thing to try in here is to restart the mongod/s

Answer (score 0):

This also occurs if the MongoDB server only accepts SSL encrypted connections. For that you need a MongoDB client compiled with SSL support.

Further readings:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#connect-to-mongodb-instance-with-ssl-encryption 
http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/tutorial/build-mongodb-from-source/

Answer (score -1):

Mine was resolved by removing SocketTimeOut parameter from the `ConnectionString::connect()` call.

i.e.

```
pDBClientBase = cs.connect(strErr /*,2 */);
```